# What step am I missing in iOS provisioning for Trigger.io?

Tags: ios, provisioning, trigger.io

I've walked through the assistant on this page:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

And then I've set up the provisioning profile this generated in my Trigger Toolkit but whenever I try to build for my device I get this:
`Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: ... no identity found`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have downloaded your Apple developer certificate and made sure it is installed in your Keychain Access. This screencast where our CTO demonstrates how to setup for iOS builds / packaging may also help:
https://vimeo.com/51652733

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was using the wrong file from the provisioning process!